# Are there any well documented code review processes and tools for Apex code changes?

Tags: version-control

We have quite a few Apex classes now. Our current process involves far too much copying and pasting, so we would like to be able to track changes to code as well as perform code review on anything that will go out. Are there any development tools similar to Github, Fisheye or Bitbucket specifically for Salesforce development? I've seen some posts about using Eclipse extensions, but was wondering if there is an easier way that doesn't require a specific IDE.

Answer (score 4):

GitHub, BitBucket, GitLab, et al. all use an underlying code versioning system, "git," which is a system for storing code revisions in a portable manner. The IDE you choose to use does not (usually) matter, although differences in the IDEs means you might need to tweak the exact process per-IDE. One developer can use MavensMate, another the Force.com IDE, and yet another Cloud9; git takes care of the mess of merging branches, line-endings, and so on, making it easily portable even across operating systems. In the end, the IDE is mostly a matter of preference. The same is also true if you choose to use SVN instead, although it seems to be less popular than git overall.

As far as "well-documented", all you need to do is [search](https://www.google.com/#q=git+salesforce) and you'll find a variety of solutions. You can even add continuous integration [into the mix](https://www.google.com/#q=ci+git+salesforce) and you'll see how you can combine systems like Jenkins, GitLab, and the Force.com IDE together. The worst part about the entire experience is that there is not one "standard" way of doing things, so it comes down to doing some research to choose which methods you'd like to use. I don't know of any single solution that is 100% out-of-the-box ready to go without some configuration (as opposed to say, a LAMP stack), but investing just a couple days of research should be enough to get started.

I would invite people to use this answer as a Community Wiki with specific links to various tactics available or anything else someone would like to add.

Answer (score 1):

We use a combination of GitHub for source control, GitHub's Pull Request workflow, and Gearset, a vendor product, for moving from org to branch or branch to org.  It is completely IDE agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [Cumuls CI.](http://developer.salesforce.org/CumulusCI/)

Answer (score 0):

We store our Salesforce metadata (code, pages, objects) in source control. Which source control engine you use is almost irrelevant, as they are language-agnostic. You could use Git, SVN, etc.

The mere thought of developing without source control makes me shiver, but that's beside the point.

We retrieve the code from our development orgs onto our local drives using the [Force.com migration tool](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Force.com_Migration_Tool). This is a great tool to deploy metadata to one or more orgs via scripts, and it may well be what you need to streamline your development lifecycle.

Once we have the metadata in our local drive, we check it into our source control system using a local Git/SVN/etc. client.

Code reviews are done in real time whenever a developer checks in. Devs are not allowed to check in unless there's somebody else available to give them a code review. If this doesn't suit the style of your organisation, you can use tools like [Crucible](https://www.atlassian.com/software/crucible) to perform code reviews after the check in has happened.

The source code in the trunk is then used to deploy to production org(s) where it can be packaged if necessary.

A CI server will automatically run tests against a couple of test orgs every time we check in.

As usual, the hardest part in all of this is to deal with the human factor. If your developers are used to make modifications in the production org, you will need to foster a culture where uploads to production happen only after check ins and code reviews.